# numpy classification comparison with 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I'm trying to do some basic classification of numpy arrays...
I want to compare a 2d array against a 3d array, along the 3rd dimension, and make a classification based on the corresponding z-axis values.

so given 3 arrays that are stacked into a 3d array:

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
a2 = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])
a3 = np.array([[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]])
a3d = dstack((a1,a2,a3))
```

and another 2d array

```
a2d = np.array([[1,2,4],[5,5,2],[2,3,3]])
```

I want to be able to compare a2d against a3d, and return a 2d array of which level of a3d is closest. (or I suppose any custom function that can compare each value along the z-axis, and return a value base on that comparison.)

**EDIT**

I modified my arrays to more closely match my data. a1 would be the minimum values, a2 the average values, and a3 the maximum values. So I want to output if each a2d value is closer to a1 (classed "1") a2 (classed "2") or a3 (classed "3"). I'm doing as a 3d array because in the real data, it won't be a simple 3-array choice, but for SO purposes, it helps to keep it simple. We can assume that in the case of a tie, we'll take the lower, so 2 would be classed as level "1", 4 as level "2".

Comment: When you are comparing a2d against a3d, how do you define "closest"?  For a given function f(a2d, a23d) what would you expect the return to be?

Comment: @perrygeo - in one specific case, I will have many years of NDVI data. I will have running cumulative min,max and average rasters, which represent a pixel level metric. I need to be able to compare any single NDVI against these cumulative metrics and classify each pixel as closer to min,max or avg. So numeric proximity to each of the three metrics, with the closest one defining the classification. In the case of a dead split, I'll probably go with the average, but it will be pretty rare, so won't really skew the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @perrygeo and @Kasra - they got me thinking in a good direction.
Since I want a classification of the closest 3d array's z value, I couldn't do simple math - I needed the (z)index of the closest value.

I did it by enumerating both axes of the 2d array, and doing a proximity compare against the corresponding (z)index of the 3d array.

There might be a way to do this without iterating the 2d array, but at least I'm avoiding iterating the 3d.

```
import numpy as np
a1 = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
a2 = np.array([[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[3,3,3]])
a3 = np.array([[5,5,5],[5,5,5],[5,5,5]])
a3d = np.dstack((a1,a2,a3))

a2d = np.array([[1,2,4],[5,5,2],[2,3,3]])

classOut = np.empty_like(a2d)

def find_nearest_idx(array,value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return idx

# enumerate to get indices
for i,a in enumerate(a2d):
    for ii,v in enumerate(a):
        valStack = a3d[i,ii]
        nearest = find_nearest_idx(valStack,v)
        classOut[i,ii] = nearest

print classOut
```

which gets me

```
[[0 0 1]
 [2 2 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

This tells me that (for example) a2d[0,0] is closest to the 0-index of a3d[0,0], which in my case means it is closest to the min value for that 2d position. a2d[1,1] is closest to the 2-index, which in my case means closer to the max value for that 2d position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following list comprehension :

```
>>> [sum(sum(abs(i-j)) for i,j in z) for z in [zip(i,a2d) for i in a3d]]
[30.0, 22.5, 30.0]
```

In preceding code i create the following list with `zip`,that is the zip of each sub array of your 3d list then all you need is calculate the sum of the elemets of subtract of those pairs then sum of them again  :

```
>>> [zip(i,a2d) for i in a3d]
[[(array([ 1.,  3.,  1.]), array([1, 2, 1])), (array([ 2.,  2.,  1.]), array([5, 5, 4])), (array([ 3.,  1.,  1.]), array([9, 8, 8]))], [(array([ 4.,  6.,  4.]), array([1, 2, 1])), (array([ 5. ,  6.5,  4. ]), array([5, 5, 4])), (array([ 6.,  4.,  4.]), array([9, 8, 8]))], [(array([ 7.,  9.,  7.]), array([1, 2, 1])), (array([ 8.,  8.,  7.]), array([5, 5, 4])), (array([ 9.,  7.,  7.]), array([9, 8, 8]))]]
```

then for all of your sub arrays you'll have the following list:

```
[30.0, 22.5, 30.0]
```

that for each sub-list show a the level of difference with 2d array!and then you can get the relative sub-array from `a3d` like following :

```
>>> a3d[l.index(min(l))]
array([[ 4. ,  6. ,  4. ],
       [ 5. ,  6.5,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  4. ,  4. ]])
```

Also you can put it in a function:

```
>>> def find_nearest(sub,main):
...     l=[sum(sum(abs(i-j)) for i,j in z) for z in [zip(i,sub) for i in main]]
...     return main[l.index(min(l))]
... 
>>> find_nearest(a2d,a3d)
array([[ 4. ,  6. ,  4. ],
       [ 5. ,  6.5,  4. ],
       [ 6. ,  4. ,  4. ]])
```

Comment: I like the approach. I'm looking for a classification for each individual value, but this is pretty cool!

Comment: @abenrob you can put this in a function!

Comment: @abenrob checkout the edit! and also if you have found this answer helpful you can tell this to community by voting and  accepting the answer ;)

Comment: I'm not getting the results I'm expecting, so I'm gonna dig deeper a little later, and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a different approach using [numpy.vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) which lets you efficiently apply a python function to each element of your array.

In this case, your python function could just classify each pixel with whatever breaks you define:

```
import numpy as np

a2d = np.array([[1,2,4],[5,5,2],[2,3,3]])
def classify(x):
    if x >= 4:
        return 3
    elif x >= 2:
        return 2
    elif x > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

vclassify = np.vectorize(classify)
result = vclassify(a2d)
```

Comment: This is good for classification based on the values in the array itself, but I'm not seeing how to use it to compare against the values in the other 3d array...

Comment: Based on example I was assuming e.g. `a1` represented a global minimum statistic that did not vary in space and could more efficiently be represented as a scalar value. If those vary over space, my answer won't work at all. But it will work for standard "classification" problems.

Comment: Yeah - bad fake data doesn't help, does it !